# Error calling click event

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Trying to figure out how to navigate through a multi-page Android app.

The XAML for my first page looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:text="WELFARE"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cmdWelfare"
        android:onClick="cmdWelfareClicked" />
    <Button
        android:text="SETTINGS"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cmdSettings"
        android:onClick="cmdSettingsClicked" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The activity is as follows:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;

namespace Welf
{
    [Activity(Label = "Welf", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        }
        public void cmdWelfareClicked(View v)
        {
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.p1);
        }
        public void cmdSettingsClicked(View v)
        {
            v.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Azure);
        }
    }
}
```

But when the button is clicked to open the next page, an unknown exception is thrown.

[image]

The error text (from Copy details) is `An unhandled exception occured. occurred`

I'm trying to learn how to do this and have no idea what could be wrong, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: I would love to, but all I get is the above. How to I get a stack trace?

Comment: Hmm. I would also suggest you to try assigning the event handler to the button in the onCreate method  and see if that solves the issue. Doing that way is recommended than assigning on click in the xml.

Comment: That works fine in a single page app, but if the page is reloaded the event will be added again and it will break. Unless you can show me how... :)

Comment: @Suraj-S E.g. is there a way to clear existing events before I add a new one?

Comment: Or is there a way to tell if a click event has already been assigned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export the method. Try like this:

```
[Export("cmdWelfareClicked")]
public void cmdWelfareClicked(View v)
{
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.p1);
}


[Export("cmdSettingsClicked")]
public void cmdSettingsClicked(View v)
{
    v.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Azure);
}
```

But why are you doing `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.p1);` inside `cmdWelfareClicked` ?, if you want to use a different layout you should start another `Activity`

Another way to do it would be to remove the `onClick` `attribute` from the `Button` in the `xml` and use the id in your `OnCreate`

Like:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

    Button buttonCmdWelfare = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.cmdWelfare);
    buttonCmdWelfare.Click += delegate {
        //Clicked
    };

    Button buttonCmdSettings = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.cmdSettings);
    buttonCmdSettings.Click += delegate {
        //Clicked
    };
}
```

And don't forget to remove `android:onClick="cmdSettingsClicked"` and `android:onClick="cmdWelfareClicked"`

Comment: Great thanks. So how do you start another activity? (I'm new to this)

Comment: Re your update, yes that's what I did before. The problem is that it's a multi-page app, and when pages are re-opened the activity is called again and the click event is assigned again, which causes an error.

Comment: @CompanyDroneFromSector7G to start new activity see [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/activity/start_an_activity/). Can you post the error? It should not cause any error, because OnCreate will be called only when OnDestroy is called so it needs to reassign the listener. I guess it is caused because you are doing `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.p1);` in the on click event (which you should not be doing)

Comment: Thank you :) I'll do it that way instead.